# How to Change order of List view's Items according to some Specific input

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, android-json

I want to change the sequence of my list view's items according to a specific input string which is matches with any of list view items contents  and that item comes on the top of list view. I have tried hard but getting no success till now.if any other query please ask.

Here is the code for fetching data from server:

Here date2 is string input which I'm trying to compare

```
    private void caladata() {

        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        // Volley's json array request object
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CALENDAR_DATA,
                new Response.Listener < String > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        //                        hidePDialog();
                        JSONObject object = null;
                        try {
                            object = new JSONObject(response);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        JSONArray jsonarray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonarray = object.getJSONArray("Table");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Calenndar_Model movie = new Calenndar_Model();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                                movie.setUserid(obj.getString("userid"));
                                movie.setHost(obj.getString("eventname"));

                                String str = obj.getString("eventdate").replaceAll("\\D+","");
                                String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), 13));
                                DateFormat timeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                timeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));

                                Date time = new Date(Long.parseLong(upToNCharacters));
//                                System.out.println(time);
                                movie.setDate(String.valueOf(timeZoneFormat.format(time)));
                                movie.setColor(obj.getString("eventcolor"));
                                movie.setAutoid(obj.getString("autoid"));

//                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server data respone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                int index=calList.indexOf(date2);
                                calList.add(movie);
                                calList.remove(date2);
                                calList.add(0, movie);


                            }  catch (JSONException e) {
                                // Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                        }



                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                        listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(selectedPos,0,300);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                //                hidePDialog();

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map < String, String > getParams() {
                Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < String, String > ();
                params.put("clientid", get1);
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class CalendarListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Calenndar_Model> movieList;

    public CalendarListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Calenndar_Model> movieList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieList = movieList;
    }

    public void swapList(List<Calenndar_Model> movieList) {
        this.movieList = movieList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_listrow, null);

        ImageView serial = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView date1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date1);

        title.setText(movieList.get(position).getHost());
        date1.setText(movieList.get(position).getDate());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Model Class:

```
public class Calenndar_Model {
    private String host, date,userid,color,autoid;

    //private double rating;

public Calenndar_Model() {
}

public Calenndar_Model(String host,String date,String userid,String color,String autoid) {
    this.host = host;
    this.date = date;
    this.userid = userid;
    this.color = color;
    this.autoid = autoid;

}

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public String getDate() {

    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {

        this.date = date;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public String getAutoid() {
    return autoid;
}

public void setAutoid(String autoid) {
    this.autoid = autoid;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I found usage of `date2` (the real name of variable, not `data2` as you menthioned in description).
All you need is to sort your `List<Calenndar_Model>`:

```
private void caladata() {

    // showing refresh animation before making http call
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    // Volley's json array request object
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, CALENDAR_DATA,
            new Response.Listener < String > () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    //                        hidePDialog();
                    JSONObject object = null;
                    try {
                        object = new JSONObject(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONArray jsonarray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonarray = object.getJSONArray("Table");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    calList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Calenndar_Model movie = new Calenndar_Model();
                            movie.setUserid(obj.getString("userid"));
                            movie.setHost(obj.getString("eventname"));

                            String str = obj.getString("eventdate").replaceAll("\\D+","");
                            String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), 13));
                            DateFormat timeZoneFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                            timeZoneFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));

                            Date time = new Date(Long.parseLong(upToNCharacters));
                            //System.out.println(time);
                            movie.setDate(String.valueOf(timeZoneFormat.format(time)));
                            movie.setColor(obj.getString("eventcolor"));
                            movie.setAutoid(obj.getString("autoid"));

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server data respone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            calList.add(movie);

                        }  catch (JSONException e) {
                            // Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }

                    //sort calList list 
                    Comparator<Calenndar_Model> calendarModelComparator = new Comparator<Calenndar_Model>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Calenndar_Model cm1, Calenndar_Model cm2) {
                            boolean firstContainsData2 = calendarModelContainsData2(cm1);
                            boolean secondContainsData2 = calendarModelContainsData2(cm2);
                            if (firstContainsData2 && secondContainsData2) {
                                return 0;
                            } else if (firstContainsData2) {
                                return -1;
                            } else if (secondContainsData2) {
                                return 1;
                            } else return cm2.getData().compareTo(cm1.getData());
                        }

                        private boolean calendarModelContainsData2(Calenndar_Model cm) {
                             return cm.getData().contains(data2);
                        }
                    };
                    Collections.sort(calList, calendarModelComparator);


                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.swapList(calList);
                    //listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(selectedPos,0,300);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //                hidePDialog();

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map < String, String > getParams() {
            Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < String, String > ();
            params.put("clientid", get1);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: it is return last json value in every listview's tems @Max.i.e. it display same and wrong value in whole list.

Comment: You have error in your original code. This line `Calenndar_Model movie = new Calenndar_Model();` have to be inside the loop because you must create new instance for each row otherwise you just modify fields of the same object with different values many times. I fixed this error in my answer.

Comment: Now I'm paste this line Calenndar_Model movie = new Calenndar_Model(); below JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);(under for loop)

Comment: ok fine it's work but requied item is on bottom but I need it on top

Comment: I modified my answer again. Check it out.

Comment: thanx @Max. Required value comes multiple time when I'm refresh listview .can U handle it it there or I ask a new question.

Comment: Just reinstantiate your `calList` and don't forget to call method 'CalendarListAdapter.swapList' after that. I modified my answer third time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose date2 is eventname you want to compare.
if(date2.equals(movie.getHost())
{
    // store Movie object on index 0, if it equals date2
    calList.add(0, movie);
}
else
{
    calList.add(movie);
}

Remove the Following Lines from caladata().
int index=calList.indexOf(date2);
calList.add(movie);
calList.remove(date2);
calList.add(0, movie);
```

Comment: Required value comes on bottom but I need it on top